# Ambiguous method overload with closures in Swift, but only when closure returns a value

Tags: swift

I found a behaviour in Swift's type resolution that I don't fully understand.
The following example compiles. My understanding is that:

- the `method` implementation is defined by the type of the `execute` closure
- the closure type is defined by its parameter `arg` in the call to `call8` (UInt8) or `call16` (UInt16) in the body of the closure.

I appreciate this feels a bit like pushing the boundaries of what the type system should be doing but I was happy to see it working properly:

```
func call8(_ arg: UInt8) { print("8")}
func call16(_ arg: UInt16) { print("16")}

struct Instruction {
    func method(name: String, execute: @escaping ((String, UInt8) -> Void)) {
        print ("1", terminator:", ")
        execute(name, 8)
    }
    func method(name: String, execute: @escaping ((String, UInt16) -> Void)) {
        print ("2", terminator:", ")
        execute(name, 16)
    }
}

let i = Instruction()

i.method(name: "test", execute: { string, arg in call8(arg)})  // prints 1, 8
i.method(name: "test", execute: { string, arg in call16(arg)}) // prints 2, 16
```

The following example is the same as the one before, except that the `execute` closure returns a value.
Now, to my surprise, this doesn't compile anymore.

```
func call8(_ arg: UInt8) { print("8")}
func call16(_ arg: UInt16) { print("16")}

struct Instruction {
    func method(name: String, execute: @escaping ((String, UInt8) -> Int)) {
        print ("1", terminator:", ")
        _ = execute(name, 8)
    }
    func method(name: String, execute: @escaping ((String, UInt16) -> Int)) {
        print ("2", terminator:", ")
        _ = execute(name, 16)
    }
}

let i = Instruction()

// These both give an error: "Ambiguous use of 'method(name:execute:)"
i.method(name: "test", execute: { string, arg in call8(arg); return 1})
i.method(name: "test", execute: { string, arg in call16(arg); return 1})
```

Can anybody please explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what's happening. It's not about returning a value. Simplify, for a clearer demonstration of that:

```swift
func call8(_: UInt8) -> String { "8" }
func call16(_: UInt16) -> String  { "16" }

func ƒ(_ call: (UInt8) -> String) { call(8) }
func ƒ(_ call: (UInt16) -> String) { call(16) }

ƒ(call8) // "8"
ƒ(call16) // "16"
```

Instead, it's all about multiple lines. Read all about it!
https://forums.swift.org/t/multiline-closure-is-not-inferring-the-return-type/40013

As for the fix, you've got to explicitly type, for disambiguation.

```swift
(string, arg: UInt8)
(string, arg: UInt16)
```

Comment: Thank you! As I said: I was very confused by the behaviour! I was not aware that the type inference in swift was targeted at single expressions. To be fair, disambiguation improves readability in my case so it's not all bad